# EditorGridPanel doesn't have row over effect in extjs

Tags: extjs

I just noticed that EditorGridPanel doesn't have row over effect as in GridPanel so i tried to add following in config

```
overCls: 'x-grid3-row-over'
```

where x-grid3-row-over is as follows (i copied from grid.css) :

```
.x-grid3-row-over {
    border-color:#ddd;
    background-color:#efefef;
    background-image:url(../images/default/grid/row-over.gif);
}
```

But i couldn't get the effect.......!!! So what should i do(except using mouseOver and mouseOut method....that is last option). May be using some kind of css?????

Please help me ......
Thanks alot in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use following in config in EditorGridPanel

```
trackMouseOver : true
```

Regards